# Access denied at all pages

Tags: 8

Suddenly, I can not access any of my pages, any page I try to visit tells me "Access Denied" and only show me site's logo, at all admin's pages and front pages. Everything happens when I install the "menu per role" module and turn it on.

Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Wild guess: The "Menu Per Role" module causes this. Did you flush caches? If the issues persist file a bug report in the module's issue queue with the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a different module. In my case it was the permissions in certain translations that were causing this to happen, if your site is using multiple languages you might want to give it a try by changing the user's language or the content's language.